# Convert string to integer and update into other field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table that has the following structure

```
[zip] = <zip, nvarchar(4),>
[cityZipID] = <cityZipID, int,>
```

In the `zip` column there is a string containing 4 digits and this is a number between 1000 an 1239 gut stored as a string.

For some reason I need to calculate an other value out of this so I need to convert the string into an integer and store it into an other column called `cityZipID`. I want to do this using SQL Server Management Studio because it has to convert about 32000 lines so I cannot easily do it by hand.

I tried the following but get only an error message when trying to execute it

```
UPDATE [MyTestData].[dbo].[Addresses]
   SET [cityZipID] = ((int)[zip])/10 -100
 WHERE [city] = 'Wien'
```

The column of `cityZipID` is null in the moment and should be filled with  numbers for the districts like the plzl for the first district is 1010 the 12th district is 1120  So the calculation would result in 1120 / 10 = 112 -100 = 12 and this would be the wanted result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Jonny

Comment: If you have a value like 1119 , then the result of the calculation that you are doing is not INT.  1119/10 = 111.9  -100 =  11.9
If decimals are allowed then change the cityZipID  to decimal(14,4)  or Float.

Comment: what is error message you are getting?

Comment: That is not valid sytanx. Use `CAST` or `CONVERT` I suggest you do some basic research on T-SQL. Also, first **SELECT** the data to understand it before updating.

Comment: @sagar The figures in plzl are 1010, 1020, and so on The division by 10 always results in a valid integer without any remaining part so we dont have 1119 we have 1110 and the next is 1120 meaning 11 and 12 district of Viena.

Comment: @MacDermaid The problem is clear because obviously it does not fit and gives an error when trying to run it. I have tried CAST and also CONVERT even in a table it says that there is an implicit conversion of string to integer so I tried but its obviously not that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
UPDATE [MyTestData].[dbo].[Addresses]
   SET [cityZipID] = (Convert(Int,[zip])/10) -100
 WHERE [city] = 'Wien'
```